# How to pass parameters to the function called by chrome.scripting.executeScripts? - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to pass a parameter to the function called by `chrome.scripting.executeScripts` but it seems that the function can't get parameters passed from the extension!

My extension contains several inputs, when one input is focused on, the extension should pass a certain parameter from the input dataset to the function executed by chrome scripting to set the value of an input in the page, author

```
let bookInputs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('book-input')];

bookInputs.forEach(bookInput=> {
    bookInput.addEventListener('focus', () => getBook(bookInput.dataset.author))
})

async function getBook(author) {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function:  () => enterBookAuthor(author)
  })
}

function enterBookAuthor(author) {
  const book= document.getElementById('book-author'); //an input in the page
  book.value = author;
}
```

But this code doesn't manage to achieve the mission, so

Why can't functions executed by chrome scripting receive parameters from the extension and what can i do to fix it??

Comment: Use `args` as shown in the documentation.

Comment: I had similar problem communicating DOM injected scripts back to Content Script. I “fixed” it by creating window custom event handling on both sides and sending messages that way (which could be calling function and sending parameters) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: @petegordon, can you share an example or reference on how you used [Custom Web Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) in your add-on?

Comment: @Gangula sorry I don't have the full specific code I can share. But, I was working with... https://github.com/josteink/gmailjs-node-boilerplate/tree/master/src. and I updated the DOM extension.js to send  ... window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("gmailjs_dom_event", {detail: newMessage})); and receive ... window.addEventListener("gmailjs_contentscript_event", (event) => {
        console.debug('content script event received by DOM', event);   and also updated the content script (extensionInjector.js) to then send "gmailjs_contentscript_event" and receive "gmailjs_dom_event"

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should use the args property, because scripting does not carry over any of the current execution context of the function.

Here's an example:

```
let bookInputs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('book-input')];

bookInputs.forEach(bookInput=> {
    bookInput.addEventListener('focus', () => getBook(bookInput.dataset.author))
})

async function getBook(author) {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    func: enterBookAuthor,
    args: [author], // this is the args property.
  })
}

function enterBookAuthor(author) {
  const book= document.getElementById('book-author'); //an input in the page
  book.value = author;
}
```

Here are the links to the docs:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#runtime-functions

Comment: how to pass args If we use a `files:` instead of `func:`?. [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection) mentions that __*`args` is only valid if the `func` parameter is specified*__

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586624/6908282) to know how to pass arguments when you use a file instead of a `func`