# Pass arguments to a file script executed by chrome.scripting.executeScripts? (manifest v3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm working on a chrome extension (manifest v3) and would like to pass arguments to a file that I mentioned in the `chrome.scripting.executeScripts`. But, the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection) mentions that ***`args` is only valid if the `func` parameter is specified***.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591250/6908282) for Manifest v2 using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` which has a solution, but i'm not able to use a similar approach in manifest v3.

### [script with `func`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71513003/6908282) (working)

```js
// popup.js
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tabId, allFrames: false },
    args: [eleID, type, offsetHeight + 10],
    func: scrollToTarget
});

function scrollToTarget(eleID, type, headerHeight = 40) {
   console.log({eleID, type, headerHeight);
}
```

---

### NOT working

#### script with `files`

> this is a similar approach to [manifest v2 `chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591250/6908282)

```js
// popup.js
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tabId, allFrames: false },
    code: `var eleID = '${eleID}'; var type = '${type}'; var headerHeight = ${offsetHeight};`
}, function () {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabId, allFrames: false },
        files: ['./executeScript.js'],
    });
});
```

### executeScrupt.js

```js
scrollToTarget(eleID, type, headerHeight);

function scrollToTarget(eleID, type, headerHeight = 40) {
   console.log({eleID, type, headerHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Option 1

executeScript in MV3 doesn't have `code` parameter so you need to rewrite it using `func` and set the arguments as properties of `window` (or its alias `self`), which is the same as a globally declared `var` for all practical purposes (assuming you don't use `world: 'MAIN'`).

```js
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: {tabId},
  args: [{eleID, type, headerHeight: offsetHeight + 10}],
  func: vars => Object.assign(self, vars),
}, () => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: {tabId}, files: ['./executeScript.js']});
});
```

#### Option 2

**Alternatively**, you can make your injected file declare the functions without calling them:

```js
// executeScript.js
function scrollToTarget(eleID, type, headerHeight = 40) {
  console.log(eleID, type, headerHeight);
}
```

Then you'll call the function after injecting the file:

```js
chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: {tabId}, files: ['./executeScript.js']}, () => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId},
    args: [eleID, type, offsetHeight + 10],
    func: (...args) => scrollToTarget(...args),
  });
});
```

Comment: Amazing answer! Should definitely go to the official doc.

Comment: The mental gimnastics you have to go through for a simple thing... thank you for the solution